# Error to map enums with MappingConstants.CASE_TRANSFORMATION

Tags: java, mapstruct

My mapstruct version is **1.5.0.Beta1**

I'm trying to use `@EnumMapping(nameTransformationStrategy = MappingConstants.CASE_TRANSFORMATION, configuration = "uppercase")` but the following error is displayed:

> java: Illegal transformation for 'case' EnumTransformationStrategy. Error: 'Unexpected configuration for enum case transformation: uppercase'.

My usecase is:

```
public enum A {
    ABCx,
    EFGy
}

public enum B {
    ABCX,
    EFGY
}

@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @EnumMapping(nameTransformationStrategy = MappingConstants.CASE_TRANSFORMATION, configuration = "uppercase")
    B convert(A a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The allowed values for the case transformation configuration are:

- upper
- lower
- capital

You can read more about it [here](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#_custom_name_transformation)

---

This question also lead to creating [mapstruct/mapstruct#2525](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2525) and to show the available options in the error message.